# Determine what types are binded with guice dependency injector

Tags: guice

Is there any way to determine what types were bound with the binder in the class which implements `Module` interface or extends the `AbstractModule` class. I need to implement a helper method which would bind some types with the binder but some of the types which this method has to bind might already be bound with the binder. Does anybody knows what happens when the same type is bound with the binder multiple times?

What about when the type is bound as a singleton?

Comment: If you bind the same type multiple times Guice throws a `CreationException` when creating the `Injector`. How are the duplicate bindings added? Are you installing another `Module` with duplicate bindings?

Comment: Generally this is the sign of an antipattern in your code. Modules should only bind types that they "own"; it's up to you to manage which modules play nicely with one another. Remember, as of Guice 3.0, ["exact duplicate bindings are ignored"](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Guice30).

Answer (score 1):

Prefer to use a helper to build a list of modules rather a helper to bind itself.

After, you can use "Modules.combine(listOfModules)" function to delete dupicate module definition :

```
Guice.createInjector(Modules.combine(listOfModules));
```

Or, when you build your "listOfModules", you can test if a module exists before add it into the list :

```
for (AbstractModule item : listOfModules) {
    if (moduleToAdd.getClass().isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())) {
        return listOfModules;
    }
}
modules.add(moduleToAdd);
return listOfModules;
```

Regards!

Comment: Pascal thank you for your answer. My problem is we have more than one(8 for now) executable projects and all of them need to configure the guice module, but many of them use objects which are defined in shared(common) code. So the guice modules are very similar. What I wanted was to make helper methods which would register dependendcies for the shared classes but since some of the shared classes have the same dependencies I need to determine which were already registered.